# eCharts xAxis labels click event

Tags: echarts

I am looking for a way to register a click event on xAxis labels. User should be able to click on xAxis label(not on the series) and we should be able to call a function.

Either a direct way or indirect way should be fine.

Comment: It is often helpful to include what you have tried so far.  Can you list all of the possible solutions you have tried?  This might help narrow down the issue for you and for us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can listen almost any events. Just enable the Axis events and filter events by params. Namely, you need to do:

1. Enable xAxis events:

```js
option = {
  // ...
  xAxis: {
    // ...
    triggerEvent: true
  }
}
```

2. Start to listen `click` events from the chart instance and check `targetType` to get all of the label's events:

```js
myChart.on('click', params => {
  if(params.targetType === 'axisLabel'){
    if(params.value === 'MyLabel #3'){
      console.log("Hello, is it me you're looking for");
      // Do something ...
    }
  }
})
```

Also you can use the shorthands and drop the `if`:

```js
myChart.on('click', { targetType: 'axisLabel', value: 'Category1' }, params => {
  console.log(params.value);
})
```

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
  var option = {
      title: {
          text: 'ECharts'
      },
      tooltip: {},
      xAxis: {
          data: ["Category1","Category2","Category3"],
          triggerEvent: true
      },
      yAxis: {},
      series: [{
          name: 'Series',
          type: 'bar',
          data: [5, 20, 36]
      }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
  
  myChart.on('click', params => {
   if(params.targetType === 'axisLabel'){
      console.log(params.value);     
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.7.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

- Highly recommend official [tutorial for events and actions](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20Actions%20in%20ECharts).
- API docs for [Events](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events)

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for. I tried everything except setting triggerEvent: true