# eCharts axisLabel formatter return html

Tags: echarts

How can we return an HTML element like anchor element using formatter function.

```
xAxis: {
    data: xAxisData,
    axisLabel: {
        formatter: function (value) {
        return "{<a href='https://www.google.com'>" + value + "</a>}";
    }
}
```

is this even possible with eCharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this labels it's not supporting. For formatting you can use [rich text](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Rich%20Text) but if you want to bind some actions on label's click check my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315486/echarts-xaxis-labels-click-event).

Comment: Yes, the previous answer helps. Thank you.