# Adjust Min/Max values of Apache Echarts Axis (X/Y) graphically or on the fly (not programmatically)

Tags: angular, echarts, ngx-echarts

I am currently implementing Echarts into my angular project and it is fine so far. However I would like to adjust the Min / Max values for my X-Axis and Y-Axis directly in the chart, graphically and without any additional functions that I need to program myself.

I would like to double click (or another type of interaction) with the Axis to define the Min/Max Value. Something like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaoMy.png)

I searched the online documentation of Apache Echarts for this possibility but did not find anything that resembled that function.
Various Zoom Options are available (inside Zoom and Slider), however no function to set those values with a precise number via some type of input in the chart.

Is this function already available with Apache Echarts?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you want something like this [eCharts xAxis labels click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315486/echarts-xaxis-labels-click-event)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! With subscribing to these events I would probably be ably to create my own dialogue which in turn can set the Min/Max values programmatically. However I am still looking if this is already included in Echarts itself via some setting.

Comment: No. It is not. Uncommon patterns are to be handled yourself.