# echarts: Make only first and last axis labels clickable (triggerEvent)?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to make *only* the first and last axis labels of the X and Y axis of a 2D line graph (so the user can set a new minimum or maximum).

```js
xAxis: {
  triggerEvent: true,
  type: 'category',
  data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  //     ^^^^^--only these should be clickable-----^^^^^
}, ...
```

Above snippet works fine, but makes the whole axis clickable and while I can get the index / column clicked the UI experience would be better with just the first and last showing up as link on hover / being clickable.

Is there any way to achieve this? I didn't find a way in the docs.

Comment: maybe this is what you looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315486/echarts-xaxis-labels-click-event)

Comment: That link does the same as the example in my post, make the whole axis clickable instead of just the first and last labels.

Comment: i think you can modify the code like this if you want only Mon and Sun should be clickable `if(params.value === 'Mon'){// Do something} else if(params.value === 'Sun'){// Do something}`

Comment: Tried that of course, but it makes the middle variables clickable but not respond. Not great from a user experience perspective.

Comment: oalah i see. i think you can't do that ? because triggerEvent do to all the xAxis. so i dont think you can prevent the clickable to be unclickable

Comment: That's how far I got and decided to ask for help here :)